# Flex item wrapping when it should not

Tags: css

I have a six items in a container that is 600px wide and each item is 100px wide. I'm using `box-sizing: border-box;`. The last item wraps onto a next line. When I remove the border from the container the items no longer wrap. But from my understanding when using ``box-sizing: border-box;``` the items should not wrap. Any ideas what is causing the items to wrap?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);
}

.container {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    height: 100vh;
}

.flex-container {
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 600px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Item 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that the container is also shrinked *(so the actual space for six 100px wide items is less than 600px)* - precisely because it also has `box-sizing: border-box` applied to it.

> border-box tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height. **If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width**.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Set the container's `box-sizing` back to `content-box` and its items will fit.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);
}

.container {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    height: 100vh;
}

.flex-container {
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 600px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.flex-item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="flex-item">Item 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unbelievable! So the container is 600px but the available width inside it (the container) is actually > 600px or perhaps 598px.

Comment: Is there a way to give the container a border that will not actually reduce the space inside it?

Comment: You can try using `outline` with a negative offset on the container _(instead of giving it a `border`)_, like so: `outline: 1px solid black; outline-offset: -1px;`